# Neo4J SDN- 3.0.0 ExecutingRestAPI.getNodeById is invoced repeatedly

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Neo4J-2.0.1 and SDN - 3.0.0.RELEASE.

I have a NodeEntity as follow:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Group {

@GraphId
Long id;

@Indexed(unique = true, indexType = IndexType.SIMPLE)
public String name;

public String property1;

public String property2;

public Group() {
}

public Group(String str) {
    name = str;
}
}
```

I have a groups repository :

```
public interface GroupsRepository extends GraphRepository<Group> {

Group getGroupByName(String name);
}
```

After the `getGroupByName(...)` method is invoked, the

> ExecutingRestAPI.getNodeById(...)

method is invoked as the number  of the properties that the Group has.

How can I avoid this kind of behaviour?

Are there any additional queries being executed under the hood?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid this behavior at the moment, it loads the dependent entities individually. The REST integration is currently not at all optimized.

Comment: I didn't mean to related entities but ordinary properties (Strings in my example) .

Comment: After checking the issue again (using Fiddler), I can see that for getting a simple node entity (with just String members/properties), I can see that the number of Rest request (http:<host>:<port>/db/data/node/<node-id>) required to complete the fetch entity action, is a function of the number of properties. It's quite dissapointing but SDN is not usable for production a.

Comment: Interesting observation. I have to check that. Most people that use SDN use it with the embedded APIs where it performs well. As I said the REST mode is currently not recommended.

Comment: Yep, I agree, you should write it in bold on the SDN documentation.

Comment: How do you do backups in embedded mode? stop the application?

Comment: @MordechaiTamam Completely agree. Neo4j guys should write this at the very top of the documentation. Most of the guys starts with SDN/REST, waste their time and then come to know about this. It's disgusting.